# Status bar in iOS remains in the last orientation view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

`Status Bar` in my application remains in the last orientation view I have selected.
In my app I am playing You tube video but I am not using web view for its playing they are automatically played after clicking on play button given by You tube site.
And also it works successfully in portrait and landscape view but if during playing mode of video I select landscape mode and stops the video then the status bar remains in the same position while the whole app moves to portrait view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sharma,

You need to set orientation as per your requirement.You can show and hide status bar as per your requirement.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Try this one !!